# Random symbols after manipulating a char array in C

Tags: c, arrays

```
void coma(char* str){
int j, i = 0;
int size = strlen(str);
int commas = (size-3)/3;
int left = (size-3)%3;
char tmp[20];

for(j = 0; j<size; i++){
    if(left || commas == 0){
        tmp[i] = str[j++];
        left--;
    }else {
        tmp[i] = ',';
        left = 3;
        commas--;
    }        
}
strcpy(str,tmp);    }

int main(){

char str[0x100];
float x = 5002052.1111;

sprintf(str,"%.2f", x);

coma(str);
printf("%s\n",str);  }
```

I am trying to insert commas every third place on a float number for example the number "5002052.1111" will be "5,002,052.11"
but when I run the program instead of getting what I am expecting I get the correct answer plus random symbols like "5,002,052.11@  {"

I notice that if I put the exact size of number in the char tmp[] it will work fine, but I need it to work with any size of numbers.

I am using gcc.

Answer (score 2):

append `'\0'` to the `tmp` string, before calling `strcpy()`

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks, OP needs to do this: `tmp[i] = '\0';` and he is done.

Comment: On that note. OP might be well-off to check boundary conditions while he's at to =P. I wouldn't put `tmp[20]` in a failsafe anytime soon.

Comment: @user2079947 cool,.. happy hacking

Comment: @user2079947 feel free to accept the answer :-) it is SO's way of thanking