# C Program that prints random symbols after correct output

Tags: c, string, printf, uppercase, lowercase

I want to make a program in C that changes lower case letter to upper case and vice versa, including symbols like . or -. When I give it an input without symbols it works perfectly ,but when I insert symbols the program prints random characters. I'm Stuck with this and I dont know why this happens.

I have already seen two post with similar questions and still haven't figured out my problem, the two posts are:

- [Why does it print random symbols when exceeding 44 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27662123/why-does-it-print-random-symbols-when-exceeding-44-characters)
- [Random symbols after manipulating a char array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918710/random-symbols-after-manipulating-a-char-array-in-c)

Input example 1:

```
asd.DSA
```

Output example 1:

```
ASD.dsa

1-\y�
```

---

Input example 2:

```
asdDSA
```

Output example 2:

```
ASDdsa
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    pid_t readWrite;
    pid_t changeString;

    readWrite = fork();

    if(readWrite == 0) {
        char str[49];
        while(fgets(str, 50, stdin) != NULL) {
            printf("%s", str);

            changeString = fork();

            if(changeString == 0) {
                int result = 0;
                char newstr[49];
                for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
                    if(str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') {
                        newstr[result++] = str[i] + 32;
                    } else if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') {
                        newstr[result++] = str[i] - 32;
                    } else {
                        newstr[result++] = str[i];
                    }
                }

                printf("%s", newstr);

                break;
            }
        }

    }
    while(wait(NULL)>0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice [mcve], +1, just missing header.

Comment: `if(str[i] >='A' && str[i] <='Z') {` is easier to read for humans.

Comment: I'm sorry already changed it.

Comment: Why do you fork ?

Comment: I use fork because the objective is for the first process to read input and print the output, while the second one is used to change the letter, but since i have this error I still haven't implemented that.

Comment: @AlexandreCarvalho Process don't share memory like thread, you will need semaphore to do that or pipe.

Comment: all that 'obscure' code.  Why not use the facilities in the header file: `ctype.h`?  I.E. `isupper()` `islower()`  `toupper()` `tolower()`,

Comment: regarding: `char str[49];
        while(fgets(str, 50, stdin) != NULL) {`  This has undefined behavior.  A possible fix: `char str[ 49 ];
        while( fgets( str, sizeof(str), stdin ) ) {

Comment: regarding: `for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {`  this is comparing a signed int to a unsigned long int.  That is not a dependable comparison.  Suggest:  `for( size_t i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {` because the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`

Comment: the function: `fork()` has three kinds of return values:  <0 means an error occurred.  ==0 means in the child process.  >0 means in the parent process.  All three conditions should be checked.  And when in the parent process, should call `wait()` or `waitpid()` so the parent does not exit first,  If the parent does exit first, then the child (on most systems) becomes a 'zombie' process that is very difficult to kill other than to reboot the computer.

Comment: the array: `newstr[]` is not being NUL terminated, so the call to `printf()` will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: this statement: `for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {`  would be better written as: `for( int i = 0; str[i]; i++ ) {

Comment: suggest changing this statement: `char newstr[49];`  to `char newstr[49] = {'\0'};

Comment: When no more input lines are available, then no call to `fork()` is made however, these two statements are still being executed: `while(wait(NULL)>0);
    return 0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `newstr` should be nul-terminated (or printed with `printf("%.*s", result, newstr)`)
- `fgets` could overflow `str` by one byte

Comment: You are right all I add to do was nul-terminate newstr, new it works fine. Thanks a lot.